# C++ if selecionar objeto

Tags: c++, if, arduino

Estou fazendo um programa para o arduino escrito em C++ para ligar e desligar leds quando um botão é pressionado.
Criei uma class Led e coloquei nela os métodos, agora escrevi um if que verifica quando um botão é pressionado, porém quero que quando o o if verifique que o botão foi pressionado ela automaticamente passa o led referente ao botão como para o método.
Algo assim.

```
if(digitalRead(led1.botão || led2.botão) == 0) { // verifica se algum botão foi pressionado

  "Ledpressionado".ligar(); // seleciona o led referente ao botão pressionado
```

Em java isso acontece automaticamente com o uso do this, mas em c++ não.

Comment: Estou assumindo que esse código esta dentro do método já que você falou que em java usaria `this`. Sendo assim, basta você usar o `this` em C++ também: `this->ligar();`

Comment: Então Tiago, na verdade o código está dentro do void loop() e não dentro dr um método da classe,por isso não consigo usar o this, já em Java eu poderia usar ele para se referir ao objeto invocou a ação.

Answer (score 1):

Não há como você fazer uma unica checagem de *"Há algum botão pressionado?"* e só com base nisso descobrir qual foi. Você inevitávelmente precisa de duas checagens, uma para cada botão. Pode fazer assim:

```
if (digitalRead(led1.botao) == 0)
    led1.ligar();

if (digitalRead(led2.botao) == 0)
    led2.ligar();
```

Ou ainda...:

```
void Led::checarBotao() {
    if (digitalRead(botao) == 0)
        ligar();
}

// ...

led1.checarBotao();
led2.checarBotao();
```

Com qualquer das duas soluções você pode trabalhar também com um loop iterando sobre uma lista de leds, em vez de escrever manualmente cada um.

Comment: Entendi Guilherme, pensei que isso fosse possível pois isso é possível em Java.
No caso ficaram duas duvidas:

1. Na linha:
    Led::checarBotao() {

Os dois pontos duplos servem para que? Já havia pesquisado e não achei nada!

2. No caso como faria esse loop itinerando sobre a lista? No caso a lista seria um array? E se eu utilizasse um while, como seria a condição para "enquanto nenhum botão da lista for clicado, continue o loop"?

Comment: Não, isso não é possivel em java ou em qualquer outra linguagem. Talvez você não tenha expressado bem o direito e da forma como entendi é uma impossibilidade lógica. 1. É a definição de uma função membro da classe. Antes declare ela dentro das classe assim: `void checarBotao();`. 2. Seria um array mesmo. `Led leds[2];`, `for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) leds[i].checarBotao();`. Para o caso do loop, pode usar uma variável booleana e setar ela para false no começo. Então no momento que qualquer das condições dos botões der verdadeiro, sete a variável para true. Poderá usar ela para controlar o while.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme.
Só mais uma pergunta, no caso o this pode ser utilizado dentro da classe para se referir ao objeto que a invocou?

Comment: @user13880 Dentro da classe pode usar o this assim: `this->ligar()`, ou meramente usar implicitamente, como fiz ali no exemplo. Chamar apenas `ligar()` vai aplicar no objeto atual.